# Getting a market supply curve from firm supply curve

Tags: supply-and-demand

PFA the image below.

[image]

As there are n firms in the market, and a tax of t moves up the cost curves of an individual firm by t units, shouldn't the cost curve of the market move up by n*t units? If yes, why does the book move the curves up only by t units. If no, could you please explain where my reasoning is going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to note is that the unit on the vertical axis is **dollars per unit**.

So if there is a tax of $\$t$ per unit, then the market supply curve will move up by $ \$ t$. (And not by $ \$nt $ as you have suggested.)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the answer by Kenny, I'd just also add that if you take a look at the horizontal axis, the curve shifts left by $n(q_1 - q_2)$ units, while the firm's quantity decreases by $q_1 - q_2$. So, in the quantity dimension, you do get that expected factor of $n$ when you look at the horizontal difference in the market vs. the firm.